# How to create a circular sector in Mapinfo?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, polygon-creation

I want to build a tool that creates a cell sector from data like that below. The sector diagram should be like the second picture. The first picture shows a Mapinfo tab file with the required fields Antenna beam, Azimuth, Band, (the radius), Latitude, and Longitude. How could I achieve this? I had a look at a link in [mapinfo-L](http://groups.google.com/group/mapinfo-l/browse_thread/thread/afa7c14627157d3a/401727cee533b541?lnk=gst&q=creating%20cell%20sector#401727cee533b541) but the solution was not conclusive!

[image: Result Cell Sector]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the MapBasic code in the zip file [here](http://www.wap3.com/download/celltower.zip). It doesn't create sectors for multiple cells, but could easily be adapted to do so.